# Is there in a Javascript function a error?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a multi-tap keypad ( like old phone ) and i need to counter how many  times need someone to press a tast for texting message(phrase), but in my compilator i have this error :
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
c:\Users\Andrei\Desktop\Facultate\An3\js projects\codewars-problems\first.js:10
if ( letters[i][j] ===phrase1[j]);
^

TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined.
How can i solve this problem?

```
  function presses(phrase) {
       let phrase1 = phrase.toUpperCase().split('');
      let counter=0;
     
      let letters = [['A','B','C'] , ['D','E','F'] , ['G','H','I'] , ['J','K','L'],['M','N','O'],['P','Q','R','S'],['T','U','V'],['W','X','Y','Z']];
      for(let i=1 ; i <=letters.length ; i++)
        {
          for(let j=1 ; j <= phrase1.length ; j++)
            {
              if (letters[i][j] === phrase1[j])
                {
                  counter +=j;
                  if(phrase1[j] === ' ')
                    {
                      counter +=1;
                    }
                }
              
            }
        }
      return counter;
    }
    
    console.log(presses("LOL"));
```

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, the array index start from 0, not 1. To loop over an array, you should change from :

```
 for(let i=1 ; i <=letters.length ; i++)
```

to :

```
 for(let i=0 ; i <letters.length ; i++)
```

The same for the inside loop. It should be :

```
 for(let j=0 ; j < phrase1.length ; j++)
```